# Extend memory allocation, fail if not possible

Tags: c, memory-management, concurrency, realloc

I'm writing a parallel program in which I must reallocate a memory block which is actively being written to by other threads. The natural way to do this is by using `realloc`, however when calling `realloc` on a block which is being written to in parallel, there are two possible outcomes:

1. `realloc` is able to expand the allocation. No problems occur.
2. `realloc` has to create a new allocation, copy the contents of the old allocation to the new allocation, and free the original allocation.

The second case is problematic for two reasons:

First, because a byte in the initial allocation can be written *after* that byte has been copied and before `realloc` returns. In that case, the write will be lost once the old allocation is freed.

Second, because `realloc` will free the old allocation before it returns, and so other threads which are concurrently accessing that memory region will be reading freed memory, which is not guaranteed to be safe.

Currently, I use a workaround, which is to `malloc`, `memcpy`, and then `free` and use a semaphore to ensure that all threads have moved over to the new allocation before calling `free` on it.

However, this approach discards the main advantage of realloc -- the possibility to extend the allocation if there is space to do so. So, my question is if there is some way to `extend_allocation` that will either extend the allocation or fail (in which case I can fall back to malloc/memcpy/free), or if I have to use malloc/memcpy/free every time?

Recommendations for alternative memory allocators that have solutions to this issue are also welcome as answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `realloc`, you need to serialize access to the pointer pointing to the allocated memory before potentially modifying the pointer.

The memory pointer should be global so any thread can reach it, along with an associated mutex or semaphore.  Anytime a thread wants to use the pointer to read or write values it first needs to lock the mutex, then unlock it when it's done.

Once you have this is place, you can easily grow the memory by locking the mutex, calling `realloc`, then unlocking it.

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct (I think the most efficient way to do what you're suggesting would be a reader-writer lock), but I think that malloc/memcpy/free will be more performant because other thread accesses never need to spin. I'll have to benchmark though, and thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Yes, a read/write lock would probably be more performant.  Also, do you do anything in between calling `malloc`, `memcpy`, and `free`?  Because if not, that's essentially the same as `realloc`.

Comment: Well, the memcpy is a bit of a simplification. There is a transition period in which the other threads start using the new allocation and fall back to the old allocation if the data they need isn't in the new allocation while the data from the old allocation is logically copied up to the new allocation. Then the old allocation is freed once all the data has propogated up. However, if I could just extend the allocation, this transitioning state could be avoided.